# Is it possible to generate test transactions from a specific blockheight?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli

Let's say I used `monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks n` to roll back my node to a specific block height. Then I want to generate some test transactions using the set of UTXOs available at that point in time.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Haven't you just asked and answered your own question? E.g. by popping blocks and then performing a tx, means you can only include outputs at that new height or earlier.

Comment: @jtgrassie I was missing one piece, which I just realized is to set `max_peers 0` so monerod will stop syncing with other nodes. That way it stays stuck on the desired block when making the txs.

Comment: Or just take the machine offline if you don't want to sync. Either way, it would be nice if you updated the question with the detail about not wanting to sync from the popped chain and then answering how you achieved it.